# TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable - working with banded/sparse matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Hello I am trying to create a banded matrix - when I try to extract the upper diagonal and add a zero to the array I get the following error - "TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable"

```
>>> A = np.eye(5, k=-1) -2 * np.eye(5) + np.eye(5, k=1)
>>> udA = np.insert (np.diag(A, 1), 0, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong - I am very new to python. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `numpy` version are you using?  In my version (1.9) your code works.

I think it's a problem using `np.diag` inside the `insert` function.

In 1.9 version, `np.diag` has this warning:

> See the more detailed documentation for `numpy.diagonal` if you use this
>   function to extract a diagonal and wish to write to the resulting array;
>   whether it returns a copy or a view depends on what version of numpy you
>   are using.

I think in new versions trying to use `np.diag` in a context where it might be assigned to produces this error.  Try:

```
np.diag(A,1) = 0
```

That probably will produce the same error.

There have been earlier questions about this issue - we need to find a good one.

[fill off diagonal of numpy array fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022178/fill-off-diagonal-of-numpy-array-fails)

Comment: I'm using 10.1.1 - and I loaded a new console and the code ran! Before I loaded it though np.diag(A,1) = 0 did produce the same error - Thank you for your time

Comment: Sounds like `np.diag` or `np.insert` had been reassigned at some point, so it was an array rather than a function.