# How to change diagonal elements in a matrix

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to change elements of the diagonal(1) of a matrix but I can't do it because of the error "assignment destination is read-only.

```
x=np.loadtxt('matrice.txt')
print(x.diagonal(1)) #2
x.diagonal(1)[0]=3
ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
```

Answer (score 0):

In numpy [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) for `diagonal` it is said

> Starting in NumPy 1.9 it returns a read-only view on the original
>   array. Attempting to write to the resulting array will produce an
>   error.
>
> In some future release, it will return a read/write view and writing
>   to the returned array will alter your original array. The returned
>   array will have the same type as the input array.
>
> If you don’t write to the array returned by this function, then you
>   can just ignore all of the above.
>
> If you depend on the current behavior, then we suggest copying the
>   returned array explicitly, i.e., use np.diagonal(a).copy() instead of
>   just np.diagonal(a). This will work with both past and future versions
>   of NumPy.

So you should use `np.diagonal(a).copy()` to get modifiable array.

If you need to edit a diagonal of your matrix you can use [this answer by Hans Then](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18081653/9263000).

```
def kth_diag_indices(a, k):
    rows, cols = np.diag_indices_from(a)
    if k < 0:
        return rows[-k:], cols[:k]
    elif k > 0:
        return rows[:-k], cols[k:]
    else:
        return rows, cols

x[kth_diag_indices(x,1)] = 2 # to make them all equal to 2
```

Comment: Thank u Mur4al. I have another problem now. I want my diagonal(1) (it has 3 elements) be only with number 2 , so i did                                   
                                                                                                      
x.diagonal(1).copy()=[2,2,2]
 File "<ipython-input-21-25a5ba9961d8>", line 1
    x.diagonal(1).copy()=[2,2,2]
                                ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: Edited the answer